# Can boost::filesystem be made to work on Nvidia Jetson (aarch64)

Tags: linux, boost, arm64, nvidia-jetson

I am trying to use [Boost 1.76.0](https://boostorg.jfrog.io/artifactory/main/release/1.76.0/source/boost_1_76_0.zip) on an Nvidia Jetson which according to `lsb_release -rc` has some Ubuntu 18.04 derivative on it and an ext4 filesystem.

Now when compiling the boost filesystem library

```
./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=filesystem
./b2
```

this succeeds, but when I execute the tests

```
libs/filesystem/test/
../../../b2
```

I get a bunch of errors about `Function not implemented`:

```
====== BEGIN OUTPUT ======
BOOST_POSIX_API is defined
BOOST_FILESYSTEM_DECL=
BOOST_SYMBOL_VISIBLE=__attribute__((__visibility__("default")))
current_path() is /home/nvidia/boost_1_76_0/libs/filesystem/test
argv[1] is '/home/nvidia/boost_1_76_0/libs/filesystem/test', changing current_path() to it
current_path() is /home/nvidia/boost_1_76_0/libs/filesystem/test
temp_dir is /home/nvidia/boost_1_76_0/libs/filesystem/test/../op-unit_test-6911-1f1d-e324
file_status test...

ERROR  ERROR  ERROR  ERROR  ERROR  ERROR  ERROR  ERROR  ERROR  ERROR  ERROR

****************************** std::exception *****************************
boost::filesystem::status: Function not implemented: "."
***************************************************************************


EXIT STATUS: 1
====== END OUTPUT ======

    LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/nvidia/boost_1_76_0/bin.v2/libs/filesystem/build/gcc-7/debug/threading-multi/visibility-hidden:/usr/bin:/usr/lib:/usr/lib32:/usr/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH

    status=0
    if test $status -ne 0 ; then
        echo Skipping test execution due to testing.execute=off
        exit 0
    fi
     "../../../bin.v2/libs/filesystem/test/operations_unit_test.test/gcc-7/debug/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/operations_unit_test" /home/nvidia/boost_1_76_0/libs/filesystem
/test  > "../../../bin.v2/libs/filesystem/test/operations_unit_test.test/gcc-7/debug/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/operations_unit_test.output" 2>&1 < /dev/null
    status=$?
    echo >> "../../../bin.v2/libs/filesystem/test/operations_unit_test.test/gcc-7/debug/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/operations_unit_test.output"
    echo EXIT STATUS: $status >> "../../../bin.v2/libs/filesystem/test/operations_unit_test.test/gcc-7/debug/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/operations_unit_test.output"
    if test $status -eq 0 ; then
        cp "../../../bin.v2/libs/filesystem/test/operations_unit_test.test/gcc-7/debug/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/operations_unit_test.output" "../../../bin.v2/libs/filesy
stem/test/operations_unit_test.test/gcc-7/debug/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/operations_unit_test.run"
    fi
    verbose=0
    if test $status -ne 0 ; then
        verbose=1
    fi
    if test $verbose -eq 1 ; then
        echo ====== BEGIN OUTPUT ======
        cat "../../../bin.v2/libs/filesystem/test/operations_unit_test.test/gcc-7/debug/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/operations_unit_test.output"
        echo ====== END OUTPUT ======
    fi
    exit $status

...failed testing.capture-output ../../../bin.v2/libs/filesystem/test/operations_unit_test.test/gcc-7/debug/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/operations_unit_test.run...
testing.capture-output ../../../bin.v2/libs/filesystem/test/copy_test.test/gcc-7/debug/threading-multi/visibility-hidden/copy_test.run
```

Specifically for my use case, the `boost::filesystem::status` seems to be the offender.
It seems to me that this exception is raised [here,](https://github.com/boostorg/filesystem/blob/boost-1.76.0/src/operations.cpp#L2622) but I'm not sure.

The initial output of `./b2` hints at some filesystem-related stuff not being available, but unfortunately I lack the knowledge to interpret this.

```
nvidia@nvidia-desktop:~/boost_1_76_0$ ./b2
Performing configuration checks

    - default address-model    : 64-bit (cached) [1]
    - default architecture     : arm (cached) [1]

Building the Boost C++ Libraries.


    - has stat::st_mtim        : yes (cached) [2]
    - has stat::st_mtimensec   : no  (cached) [2]
    - has stat::st_mtimespec   : no  (cached) [2]
    - has stat::st_birthtim    : no  (cached) [2]
    - has stat::st_birthtimensec : no  (cached) [2]
    - has stat::st_birthtimespec : no  (cached) [2]
    - has statx                : no  (cached) [2]
    - has statx syscall        : yes (cached) [2]
    - has stat::st_mtim        : yes (cached) [3]
    - has stat::st_mtimensec   : no  (cached) [3]
    - has stat::st_mtimespec   : no  (cached) [3]
    - has stat::st_birthtim    : no  (cached) [3]
    - has stat::st_birthtimensec : no  (cached) [3]
    - has stat::st_birthtimespec : no  (cached) [3]
    - has statx                : no  (cached) [3]
    - has statx syscall        : yes (cached) [3]
```

---

What is the reason that some filesystem functions would be unavailable on a system made of an ext4 filesystem and an Ubuntu 18.04 linux?
Can this be patched without too much effort?

Comment: Depends on the libc you've got there. It will work on cross-compiled glibc just fine, but your system probably has a different variety (musl or whatever).

Answer (score -1):

Update 1: Response to your comment. I am trying to help you here, have you made any effort to read the Error output, or try the options I gave you.

Based on your below comment below that *..it does not address how to compile...*.

*My answers gives you not `1` but `3` `option`/solutions* to recompile to your specific target, *with full reference* documentations & `turn key tool chains`, in your case you can do it for ARM target.

---

**Your question:**
*... some filesystem functions would be unavailable on a system made of an ext4 filesystem and an Ubuntu 18.04 linux? Can this be patched without too much effort?....*

My answer in option 2, tries to give you a solution without too much effort so that you pull ahead of time or use already existing libs and compile .. more options on how to configure [here..](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html)

---

*It looks like you have put very little effort and not invested time to read or understand your own error messages*.

[image: Boost Filesystem Error]

---

Original Answer:

Based on your posted error message, your file/func/path seems to be an issue, its not finding the function/files; or [unable to create test directories](https://github.com/boostorg/filesystem/issues/124)

**option 1:**

Suggestion make your life easier, by using something like [Conan](https://conan.io/) that allows easy cross compiling by leveraging profiles

1. easily cross-compile by plugging in the profile you select
2. switch or pick which version of Boost you want.
3. Best is that, it integrates really well with `CMake`

---

**Option 2:**

```
// try to use built in version of cmake, might take you back a version
set(BOOST_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
```

This helps your configure your compile files dependencies, since your question you shared a concern on finding files vs caching some.., more [here..](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindBoost.html)

> It maybe failing in the test section since its not able to create the directory as well.. make sure you give it permissions. Go [here to see it on github](https://github.com/boostorg/filesystem/issues/124)

---

**Option 3:**

Completely remake/rebuild, I like this to ensure your tool chain has fresh and latest, but if you have custom paths etc, look further below

```
sudo apt-get install cmake libblkid-dev e2fslibs-dev libboost-all-dev libaudit-dev
```

if that still doesn't work, set up boost from `cmake` in a file... `CMakeList.txt`, as an example, update paths to your installation of boost.

```
SET (BOOST_ROOT "/opt/boost/boost_1_xx")
SET (BOOST_INCLUDEDIR "/opt/boost/boost-1.xx.0/include")
SET (BOOST_LIBRARYDIR "/opt/boost/boost-1.xx.0/lib")
SET (BOOST_MIN_VERSION "1.xx.0")
set (Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE ON)
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost ${BOOST_MIN_VERSION} REQUIRED)
if (NOT Boost_FOUND)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Fatal error: Boost (version >= 1.xx) required.")
else()
  message(STATUS "Setting up BOOST")
  message(STATUS " Includes - ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
  message(STATUS " Library  - ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}")
  include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
  link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
endif (NOT Boost_FOUND)
```

searching default paths (`/usr`, `/usr/local`) or the path provided through the cmake variables (`BOOST_ROOT`, `BOOST_INCLUDEDIR`, `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR`)

Latest version is [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html) with steps for the Linux (UNIX variants)

Comment: This answer appears to not address the question: It is not about how to include boost in a project, but compiling it from source on Arm64, with the result that some of boost's filesystem tests fail and some functionality is unavailable at runtime.

Comment: Look in option 2, it address some files that are cached vs. uncached,  manually configure your files to avoid missing your dependencies on your arm64 `SET (BOOST_INCLUDEDIR "/opt/boost/boost-1.xx.0/include")
    SET (BOOST_LIBRARYDIR "/opt/boost/boost-1.xx.0/lib")
    SET (BOOST_MIN_VERSION "1.xx.0")
    set (Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE ON)
    FIND_PACKAGE(Boost ${BOOST_MIN_VERSION} REQUIRED)
    if (NOT Boost_FOUND)
      message(FATAL_ERROR "Fatal error: Boost (version >= 1.xx) required.")`

Comment: If the the options listed still doesn't work, let me know I will give you another soln.. I was able to compile it was a directory issue for me, I pulled everything locally and made sure I had all my dependencies to build and target both Arm 32 and 64  and it worked for me.